# Incompatible types (boolean/string)

Tags: java

I'm trying to check if my input is a consonant. However it tells me at the line below that they are incompatible types (boolean vs String)

```
if (medeklinkerGeraden = medeklinkers [r]) {
```

^

```
public String medeklinkerRaden ()  {
    String medeklinkerGeraden = "";
    boolean bevatMedeklinker = false;
    System.out.println("U mag een medeklinker gokken!");
    medeklinkerGeraden = Input.readString();
    String [] medeklinkers = {"b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z"};
    do {
        for (int r = 0; r < medeklinkers.length; r++)
            if (medeklinkerGeraden = medeklinkers [r]) {
                bevatMedeklinker = true;
            }

    }
    while (! bevatMedeklinker);

    return medeklinkerGeraden;
}
```

Comment: use == instead of =, or in your specific case as you are comparing Strings use the equals method.

Comment: First, = and == are different. Second, == is only very rarely toefl for comparing strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor like this:

```
 if (medeklinkers[r].equals(medeklinkerGeraden)) {
            bevatMedeklinker = true;
 }
```

Comment: Will do, but can't yet :) 5 minutes to go

Comment: Because `medeklinkers` is constant, it's better to write `medeklinkers[r].equals(medeklinkerGeraden)` to minimise potential NPE risk. :)

Comment: If your array has no element then null will get pass to method which will throw exception as NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

You must use  `==` instead of `=`

```
 if (medeklinkerGeraden == medeklinkers [r])
```

Comment: don't use == to compare String

Comment: I appreciate the effort agim, still upvoted you because of that. == did initially fix the fault but I know now that I shouldn't use == to compare strings! Thanks everybody

Comment: +1 Even though its not entirely correct in regards to String equality.

Comment: Thank's @smit. Actually I know it and I'm a little bit ashamed for this mistake ;)

Comment: @agim Its not a mistake. It happens to all of us, so don't be ashamed, we are human after all. I will suggest to add some description to your answer why this does not correct way.